# Can we use enums as typesafe entity ids?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We are working with a rather large model in a EF 6.1 code first setup and we are using ints for entity ids.

Unfortunately, this is not as typesafe as we would like, since one can easily mix up ids, for example comparing ids of entities of different types (myblog.Id == somePost.Id) or similar. Or even worse: myBlog.Id++.

Therefore, I came up with the idea of using typed ids, so you cannot mix up ids. 
So we need a BlogId type for our blog entity.  Now, the obvious choice would be to use an int wrapped in a struct, but you cannot use structs as keys. And you cannot extend int... - wait, you can! Using enum!

So I came up with this:

```
public enum BlogId : int { } 
public class Blog
{
    public Blog() { Posts = new List<Post>(); }
    public BlogId BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
internal class BlogConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Blog>
{
    internal BlogConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(b => b.BlogId);
        Property(b=>b.BlogId)
           .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

So now we have typesafe ids - comparing a BlogId and a PostId is a compile time error.
And we cannot add 3 to a BlogId.
The empty enums may look a bit strange, but that is more of an implementation detail.
And we have to set the DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity option explicitly in our mapping, but that's a one-time effort.

Before we start converting all our code to this pattern, are there any obvious problems?

Edit:
I probably need to clarify why we must work with ids instead of full entities in the first place. Sometimes we need to match entities in EF Linq queries - and comparing entities doesn't work there. For example (building on the blog example and assuming a somewhat richer domain model): Find comments on the current users blog entries. Remember, that we want to do it in the database (we have lots of data) and we assume there are no direct navigational properties. And the currentUser is not attached. A naive approach would be

```
from c in ctx.Comments where c.ParentPost.Blog.Author == currentUser
```

This doesn't work, since you cannot compare entities in EF Linq.
So we try

```
from c in ctx.Comments where c.ParentPost.Blog.Id == currentUser.Id
```

This compiles and runs but is wrong - it should have been

```
from c in ctx.Comments where c.ParentPost.Blog.Author.Id == currentUser.Id
```

Typesafe ids would have caught it. And we have much more complex queries than this. Try "find comments to current users blog entries made by specific other user which the current user has not himself commented on later".

Regards, Niels

Comment: This is a clever idea but I am not fully convinced. Using an O/R mapper should usually avoid dealing with IDs directly to a large extend so I am not sure how much can be gained. If you are building low level infrastructure like caches or distributing entities across tiers you are more likely to have to deal with IDs and this may help avoiding bugs. On the other hand it may also get into your way if you have to deal with different entity types in a single spot and you have somewhat heterogeneous keys.

Comment: The challenge is that we will sometimes be reusing master data objects in different contexts. For example, assume that each blog post is associated with a category from  a global list of categories. Now, when saving a blog post, we just want to set the CategoryId of the post without attaching the category entity object to the context - especially since many posts may be using the same category item at the same time.

Comment: Wouldn't then extension methods like `SetCategory(this Blog blog, Category category) { blog.CategoryId = category.Id; }` be even a better solution?

Comment: Hmm - maybe. I still think we have many places in non-mapped data structures where we would like to refer to entities by id - for example when storing preferred categories in a client session.

Comment: I have seen this idea for the first time and could only speculate about what kind of issues may be waiting behind the curtain. I wouldn't even be surprised if (almost) no one tried that before and can offer help. So essentially I was think whether it might be better to contain the issue instead of trying to make it safe everywhere. But you are right, if IDs pop up in enough places containing may be hard or laborious on its own.

Comment: One thing is that the compiler won't allow a simple LINQ statement like `context.Blogs.Where(b => b.BlogId == 1)`. You'll always have to cast `1` to `BlogId`. That may have wide-ranging consequences. Also, any foreign key properties must have the same enum types, otherwise joins won't work.

Comment: This seems like a neat trick, but this is software development: the devil is in the details. My bet is that after months of using this approach, it won't be worth the overhead.

Comment: @GertArnold This should not be an issue; you will not have any hard coded IDs in the code, at least you shouldn't. And when you get them out of a (foreign) key field they will have the correct type.

Comment: Just as a remark: "The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong." Take care that Guid is not included. At some time Int32 will run out of values, and you'll have to move to something different.

Comment: `c.ParentPost.Blog.Author == currentUser` works flawlessly in nHibernate

Comment: WOW! @niels-harremoes that's amazing. I've heared about typesafe IDs in Haskell for few years ago. Then I relized that it can be implemented in Hibernate, as it can map any custom type to column, using custom type mapping, But this idea seems really nice! Have you succeeded in implemented it? Was it going well?

P.S. additionaly considering using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622502/entity-framework-6-code-first-custom-type-mapping  [ComplexType]  complex types

Comment: My suggestion was voted down by the rest of the team as being too innovative (i.e. not a well-known pattern), so we didn't go ahead with it.

Answer (score 3):

It's an interesting approach, but the question is: is it worth it and what are the consequences?

You could still do something like

```
 if ((int)blog.BlogId == (int)comment.CommentId) { }
```

Personally I would invest more time in educating people, writing good tests, and code reviews, instead of trying to add some form of extra complexity that influences the way you use and query your entities.

Think - for example:

- What effect does this casting have on performance in LINQ queries?
- How would you enforce this if you expose your operations through Web API of WCF?
- Does this work with navigation properties??
- Also, you are limited in the types you could use as primary key; I don't believe this works with Guids.

A way of additional protection is to have your domain layer handle these kinds of things by accepting entity instances instead of ID's.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, @L-Three. Of course, you would still be able to cast away the safety - but I'm trying to prevent people from accidently shooting themselves on the foot, not foiling Moriarty. I don't think there should be any performance penalties - it will all be ints in the database and at runtime anyway. The WCF issue will need to be considered - but currently, WCF is not a priority for us. From my tests, it works fine with navigation. And yes, it only works with int keys, not Guids.

Comment: The whole idea that it does NOT affect the way you use and query your entities. All correct code will look just like before - possibly except for dummy entities created for unit tests.

Comment: I don't think the argument that you could misuse by downcasting both types is valid. You could say there's no point in type safety at all because you can still do `if((object)blog == (object)comment) { }`. It's just about getting the compiler to catch mistakes at compile time

Answer (score 2):

I was not even familiar with this usage, but did a little digging and even the EF team says it's do-able. From their initial blog post on enum support in EF, this is listed:

**Enums as keys**
In addition, properties of enum types can participate in the definition of primary keys, unique constraints and foreign keys, as well as take part in concurrency control checks, and have declared default values.

source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/06/29/enumeration-support-in-entity-framework.aspx

I have not ever done this myself, but that quote gives me confidence. So it's possible, but as L-Three suggests: really consider if it's what you want (pros & cons .. but sounds like you have already done that) and test test test!

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to this party, but I've used this technique and it definitely works!

Type safety works exactly as you suggest. Compiler will catch mistakes such as

```
from c in ctx.Comments where c.ParentPost.Blog.Id == currentUser.Id
```

And it prevents silly maths.

```
currentUser.Id++;
currentUser.Id * 3;
```

Navigation properties still work fine too, as long as both ends of the navigation are the same enum type.

And the SQL queries work just as they do with an `int`.

It's certainly an interesting idea!

**Can** you use typesafe entity IDs? - Yes!

**Should** you? I'm not sure. It doesn't seem that this is how EF was designed and feels a little hacky.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't try to bash you, but how can one mix up Ids of Type X with Ids of Type Z?
I never met anybody who did stuff like myBlog.Id++ either (or at least not without getting fired).

Anyhow, here is a solution which seams to be less work and better maintainable (especiall for the db-admins):

-In the TypeConfiguration, create an Id through the fluent API (you'll see why later)

-Create an abstract base-class for all your entities with:

*property: proteced int Id

*method: public int getIdValue()

*method: public bool isSameRecord(T otherEntity) where T: EntityBaseClass

I guess the first method are self-explanatory, the isSameRecord will take the other instance of your base-class, does a type-check first and if it passes it, it will do a id-checkup, too.

---

This is an untested approach, there's a good chance you can't create protected identifiers.

If it doesn't work, you could create public int _id and just tell your team to not use it directly.

Comment: Hi @Richard. The problem we're running into is when using Linq to EF queries. For example: Find comments on the current users blog entries
`from c in ctx.Comments where c.ParentPost.Blog.Author == currentUser` 
This doesn't work, since you cannot compare entities.
So we try
`from c in ctx.Comments where c.ParentPost.Blog.Id == c.Author.Id`
This compiles and runs but fail - it should have been
`from c in ctx.Comments where c.ParentPost.Blog.Author.Id == c.Author.Id`
Typesafe ids would have caught it. And we have much more complex queries than this!

Comment: Testing would find a problem like that. But better yet, you should also implement repositories so that developers who would make a mistake like that aren't randomly writing queries anyway.

Comment: Type safe identifiers save a lot of time - in the long run, trust me!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will work in EF but one thing you could do is to have your entities implement `IEquatable<T>`:

For example your `Blog` class:

```
public class Blog : IEquatable<Blog>
{
    // other stuff
    public bool Equals(Blog other)
    {
        return this.Id.Equals(other.Id);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use a more flexible ORM such as NHibernate. If this is of interest, let me know and I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work with EF linq queries. So it will not really help us that much.